# move to a directory having special characters using shell script

Tags: shell

I have folder named apache-tomcat-6.0.29. How do I cd to this directory using shell script?

Can someone help please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

...what's wrong with:

```
cd apache-tomcat-6.0.29
```

?

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple.use [CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_%28command%29)

```
cd pathto/apache-tomcat-6.0.29
```